# Postgis+Postgresql:If any point from set A is in the r-neighborhood of any point form set B

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a table using Linestring to record the trajectory of users:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id serial DISTINCT,
  trajectory Geometry(LINESTRING)
);
```

My question is: given a set of Points B, how to select all the users who have been near points in B. (Users who have been nearer than n meters to any point in B)

I tried googled "postgis if any point in Linestring" but found nothing. The way I can think of is to create a new table like this (Split the row in the first table, one row for one point a user have been to) and then using functions on single point:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  user_id serial,
  have_been_to_point Geometry(POINT)
);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Could you please also add some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue that a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html) would suffice. Based on this `LINESTRING` ..

```
INSERT INTO users (trajectory) VALUES 
('LINESTRING(7.44 51.50,6.96 51.42,6.94 50.97,7.42 50.75)');
```

[image]

... you can dump the points with [`ST_DumpPoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) in a CTE and use it in your query to check the distance using [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) (or use any other function). In the query bellow I'm using `GEOGRAPHY` just to get the [distance in meters](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54435/how-to-show-postgis-distance-in-meter) to `POINT(7.02 50.92)` - which is close to the 3rd node of the trajectory:

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT id,(ST_DumpPoints(trajectory)).geom 
  FROM users)
SELECT j.id, ST_Distance(j.geom::GEOGRAPHY,
             ST_GeographyFromText('POINT(7.02 50.92)')) 
FROM j;


 id |  st_distance   
----+----------------
  1 |  70887.3073306
  1 | 55783.82586626
  1 |  7908.96974024
  1 |  33936.3582915
(4 Zeilen)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ST_DWITHIN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) to find the lines near a point of interest. Let's note that this point doesn't have to be near a line vertex.

Depending on the projection you use, you may want to cast to geography to use meters.

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    st_dwithin(trajectory,
          ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(-70 45)'),
          1000) as nearMyPoint
FROM users;
```